# Как сделать историю переходов по меню?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть шесть тегов `button`, к примеру, каждый имеет свой класс от одного до пяти. И есть шестая кнопка с классом `back`. Есть массив в который будут записываться, имена классов кнопок по которым нажали. `mass = [1,2,2,3,1]`

Проблема в том , что не могу понять как при нажатии на кнопку назад вызывать из массива истории те кнопки по которым нажали, в нужном порядке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var mass=[1,2,2,3,1];
var back_index=mass.length;

$('button_back').click(function(){ console.log(mass[back_index]; back_index--;)})
```

Алгоритм такой:
В массив заносятся названия классов в том порядке в котором нажимаются кнопки. `mass.push(имя_класса)`
Далее необходимо объявить переменную и занести туда количество элементов массива `var back_index=mass.length;`. Затем пишем функцию, которая берет последний индекс массива и выполняет нужные действия с этим элементов. Затем необходимо вычесть из индекса 1, так как мы уже использовали элемент с этим индексом массива.